# Is there a way to point bitcoin-qt from inside linux to the blockchain i downloaded in windows?

Tags: blockchain, linux

I duel boot and would like to point linux to the blockchain i downloaded in windows rather than download it again.

Comment: Interesting question. Will you use bitcoin-qt also from windows, or another client?

Comment: I figured it out. change your bitcoin-qt datadir to /media/L/users/*Namehere*/appdata/roaming/bitcoin/ run bitcoin-qt from terminal and if you haven't ever run it, the directory location box should be the first thing that pops up. You have to access  the windows partition at least once before you do this. works like a charm. I dont get any errors going back and forth between Linux and windows.